# Given $G,H_1,H_2$ finite abelian groups and $G\times H_1 \cong G\times H_2$ then $H_1 \cong H_2$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

> Given $G,H_1,H_2$ finite abelian groups and $G\times H_1 \cong G\times H_2$
>   Show $H_1 \cong H_2$

I think the proof would go something like this:
$H_1\cong(G\times H_1)/(G\times\{e_{H_1}\})\cong(G\times H_2)/(G\times\{e_{H_2}\})\cong H_2$

Though the first and third isomorphisms are somewhat obvious, I'm doubtful about the second isomorphism because
Given $\Phi:G_1 \to G_2$ is an isomorphism, I only know that (this is a guess) $G_1/H\cong G_2/\Phi(H)$ (is this true? I have not verified)
But $\Phi((G,e_{H_1}))$ may not be equal to $(G, e_{H_2})$

So how do I show this?

Comment: This line of thinking would lead one to assume that if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are isomorphic subgroups of the finite Abelian group $G$ then $G/H_1\cong G/H_2$. But that's not true.

Comment: I suspect there is no really easy proof of this. You can use the structure theory of finite Abelian groups (they are essentially uniquely products of cyclic groups of prime power order) of the real sledgehammer of the Krull-Schmidt theorem.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown example for the first comment?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Regarding your first comment, I think it is true if $H_1$ is carried to $H_2$ by an automorphism of $G$.

Comment: @trisct Does this also mean the following is true?  Given $Φ:G_1→G_2$ is an isomorphism, then $G_1/H \cong G_2/Φ(H)$

Comment: I think so, use the isomorphism theorem on $G_1\to G_2/\Phi(H)$ ($G_2$ needs to be abelian, of course). But I haven't figured out the problem that maybe $\Phi((G\times\{e_{H_1}\})\neq(G\times\{e_{H_2}\})$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have an answer below. Need some proof-verification though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G,H_1,H_2$ be finite abelian groups. Let $\Phi$ be an isomorphism as follows
$$\Phi:G\times H_1\to G\times H_2$$
We write $\Phi$ as its components: $\Phi=(\Phi_1,\Phi_2)$ where
$$\Phi_1:G\times H_1\to G,\quad\Phi_2:G\times H_1\to H_2$$
are surjective group homomorphisms. Then they induce isomorphisms
$$G\cong\frac{G\times H_1}{\ker\Phi_1},\quad H_2\cong\frac{G\times H_1}{\ker\Phi_2}$$

> **Lemma 1.** The following are isomorphisms
>   $$\phi_1=\Phi_1|_{\ker\Phi_2}:\ker\Phi_2\to G$$
>   $$\phi_2=\Phi_2|_{\ker\Phi_1}:\ker\Phi_1\to H_2$$
>
> *Proof.* Apparently $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are homomorphisms. We first prove that $\phi_1$ is injective. Let $(a,b),(c,d)\in\ker\Phi_2$ be such that
>   $$\Phi_1(a,b)=\Phi_1(c,d)$$
>   Then $\Phi_1(ac^{-1},bd^{-1})=1_G$. On the other hand, $\Phi_2(ac^{-1},bd^{-1})=1_{H_2}$, since $(a,b),(c,d)\in\ker\Phi_2$. This means $\Phi(ac^{-1},bd^{-1})=(1_G,1_{H_2})\implies(ac^{-1},bd^{-1})\in\ker\Phi\implies a=c,b=d$ as $\Phi$ is an isomorphism. Now note that
>   $$G\times H_1\cong G\times H_2\implies|H_1|=|H_2|$$
>   $$H_2\cong\frac{G\times H_1}{\ker\Phi_2}\implies|H_2|=\frac{|G||H_1|}{|\ker\Phi_2|}$$
>   We get
>   $$|G|=|\ker\Phi_2|$$
>   Hence $\phi_1$ is an injective homomorphism between two groups with equally many elements, and therefore an isomorphism. By the same argument $\phi_2$ is also an isomorphism.

$\quad$

> **Lemma 2.** Every $(a,b)\in G\times H_1$ can be written uniquely as
>   $$(a,b)=xy,\ x\in\ker\Phi_1,\ y\in\ker\Phi_2$$
>
> *Proof.* Let
>   $$x=\phi_2^{-1}\Phi_2(a,b)\in\ker\Phi_1,\quad y=\phi_1^{-1}\Phi_1(a,b)\in\ker\Phi_2$$
>   This means
>   $$\Phi(x)=(\Phi_1(x),\Phi_2(x))=(1_G,\Phi_2(a,b))$$
>   $$\Phi(y)=(\Phi_1(y),\Phi_2(y))=(\Phi_1(a,b),1_{H_2})$$
>   $$\implies\Phi(xy)=\Phi(x)\Phi(y)=(1_G,\Phi_2(a,b))(\Phi_1(a,b),1_{H_2})=(\Phi_1(a,b),\Phi_2(a,b))=\Phi(a,b)$$
>   $$\implies(a,b)=xy$$
>   Suppose $(a,b)=xy=x'y'$ with $x',y'$ also as above. Then $\Phi_1(y)=\Phi_1(xy)=\Phi_1(x'y')=\Phi_1(y')$. But $\Phi_1$ restricted to $\ker\Phi_2$ is injective, hence $y=y'$. similarly $x=x'$.

Now we write elements in $G\times H_1$ as in Lemma 2 and define this mapping
$$G\times H_1\to G\times H_1$$
$$xy\mapsto(\phi_1(y),\phi_2(x))$$
This is easily verified to be an automorphism that carries $\ker\Phi_2$ to $G$. By my comments above
$$\frac{G\times H_1}{\ker\Phi_2}\cong\frac{G\times H_1}{G}$$
Combined with (obtained above Lemma 1)
$$H_2\cong\frac{G\times H_1}{\ker\Phi_2}$$
we have
$$H_2\cong\frac{G\times H_1}{\ker\Phi_2}\cong\frac{G\times H_1}{G}\cong H_1$$